# Confused about the cout operator behavior with string and int

Tags: c++, c++11, cout

I ran this particular code

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<(3 + "Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

The output is
`llo World`

I am pretty confused why I am getting this output, can anyone please care to explain.

Comment: Do you really get `llo World` and not `lo World`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hello World" is an array. When you use the value of an array, it implicitly converts to a pointer to first element - i.e. pointer to the character 'H' in this case. When you add an integer N to a pointer, the result is a pointer to the N'th next sibling element of the array. In this case, "Hello World" + 3 is a pointer to the second 'l' character. When you insert a pointer to character into a character stream, it prints the content of the array starting from the pointed element until a null terminator character.

Comment: If you tell them how they can actually print 3 and Hello World together, I'd think it would make your answer perfect :)

Comment: @MahanGM I'm not sure if it's relevant to the question, so I'll add it here: `std::cout << "3Hello World";`

Comment: No I meant as in adding another shifting operator like `std::cout << 3 << "Hello World";`, but that's your answer, I'm not going to interfere.